# during a year/during the year

Tags: articles

Which article should be used?

> 1 A lot of tourists come to our town during **the** year/**a** year.
>
> 2 How many days are there in **the/a** year?

I come across either.

Comment: Regardless of the article, I don't understand the point of ***during a/the year*** here. When ***else*** could they come? It's perfectly natural to say *A lot of tourists come to our town during the **summer***, obviously.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "during a/the year" makes no sense to me in this context.

Comment: I could cone during the winter. But if I say during the years it means that people come during all four seasons.

Comment: No - if you say "during the years" it means that you're not a native Anglophone! If people come during all four seasons we say "all year round" or "all year long" (or "throughout the year").

Comment: Years was a typo. I meant year. So, if to say "during a year" is wrong and it should be "all year round", why is it that it's OK to say "during the winter"? Or do you also say "all winter round"?

Comment: You can say *during the winter, during the day, during the morning* because *winter, day, morning* are only *part* of all the relevant time. Note that *during the day* can only refer to *day = daylight hours* in such contexts; it can't mean a 24-hour period, because that would be the same error as your *during the year*. And although in theory ***all day round*** should be possible with the sense of *day = 24 hours*, we simply never say that; it's always ***all day long*** or ***throughout the day***.

Comment: (Note that *all year round* figuratively invokes the concept of a year as a ***circular*** timeframe that starts again when it reaches the "end". Again, in principle, a *week* is "circular" in the same way, but we never say ***all week round*** either. Sometimes there's no obvious reason for such inconsistencies, though. See [all day / all the year round.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/313892/all-day-all-the-year-round))

Answer (score 1):

Just remove it, because it doesn't make sense.  "A lot of tourists come to our town" means "They come at a high rate", you don't need to mention "a year" (or per year, etc)

You don't need to say "during the year" because that just means "at any point in time" which is meaningless.

You could say "A lot of tourists come every year", or "A lot of tourists come during the summer" or "in October".

For the second example, you'd probably used "in a year", unless "the year" could be understood from context to be a specific year.

Comment: I am surprised to see that you interpret "during" as  "at any point in time". Here is a definition https://www.wordreference.com/definition/during  throughout the duration of: He lived in Florida during the winter. Your definition is also there but it's not the only one.

Comment: No, I'm saying "during a year" is more or less meaningless.  As It is always during a year.  On the other hand "during a winter" is meaningful, as it is not always winter.

Answer (score 1):

The second example is pure grammar...

- How many days are there in the year?

Definite article: this year is 2023, so the answer is 365.

- How many days are there in a year?

Indefinite article: 365, or 366 if it is a leap year.

The first example feels a bit strange, but the same grammar rules apply. I can make it work with either...

- A lot of tourists come to our town during the year/a year.

Normally we get a few thousand tourists come to our town during a year. Because of the total eclipse, over a hundred thousand came during last year.

NB: I found this very hard to type. My fingers wanted to put "Thousands of visitors a year come to our town." If the visitors are steadily coming, a few a day is thousands per year; but *a lot* per year has little meaning.

Comment: If "the year" is a current year than what would "the winder mean"? "A lot of tourists come to our town during the winter." Does it mean the current winter or every winter?

Comment: @user1425 I think the same rules apply. 'Most tourists come in the winter' feels right, and 'Most tourists come in a winter' does not. We refer to a particular season out of four, so the definite article is right. Example of the indefinite: *A modern winter is warmer than a winter from Dickens' childhood.*

Comment: I see it differently. When you say "the year" you mean the current year. But when you say "the winter" it's not clear which winter is implied - the current winder OR some winter. It's tricky. The year means THIS YEAR but THE WINTER means every winter.